# Finding IP of a Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins

A windows slave node connected to Jenkins server through "Java web start". The system information of the node doesn't have it's IP address.

I had to run through all the slaves node we had, and find which machine (ip address) corresponds to the slave node in Jenkins.

Is there a way to find the IP address of a slave node from Jenkins itself?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Through the Script Console (*Manage Jenkins* -> *Nodes* -> *Select a node* -> *Script Console*) of the node we can execute groovy script. Run the following command to get the IP address.

```
println InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName
```

Comment: To get the actual IP address (as requested originally) I used the Script Console, but executed `println InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress` instead.

Comment: Neither of these seem to work for Linux... or at least not my Ubuntu VM node.

Comment: This works fine for a single node (at least when it's running Linux), but **you cannot get an overview on _all_ nodes with that**, since it **requires selecting each node's script console** individually. There's a more generic solution in my answer, you may want to give that a try.

Comment: this one giving error `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.net.InetAddress getLocalHost. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.net.InetAddress getLocalHost
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:189)`

Comment: This will always print the name / ip of the master, not the slave node

Answer (score 36):

The most **efficient** and **platform-independent** way to find out the IP is probably the following **groovy code** for the "global" Script Console **on the master**:

```
import hudson.model.Computer.ListPossibleNames

def node = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNode( "myslave" )
println node.computer.getChannel().call(new ListPossibleNames())
```

In the console, this yields (for example)

```
Result
[192.168.0.17]
```

The result is a list of strings, as there's potentially multiple IP addresses on one machine.

Since this does not require  the *node-specific* consoles, **it's easy to add a loop around the code that covers *all* nodes**.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is the only solution that runs on the master. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (To be precise, the script runs on the master; it delegates listing of IPs to the slave node via remoting).

Comment: This requires whitelisting for security, so not useable on locked down jenkins :(

Comment: @ablarg: Yes, you need permission to run groovy scripts. At least for the global script console, this will only be possible when granted admin privileges. However, permissions to execute specific scripts might be granted to normal users via [in-process script approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/).

Answer (score 23):

To answer this same question on a non-windows Jenkins slave:

Get the IP address:

```
println "ifconfig".execute().text
```

Get the hostname:

```
println "hostname".execute().text
```

Comment: Excellent addition to the post. It took me a while to look through ALL of the answers to a question on SO.

Comment: This requires whitelisting for security, so not useable on locked down jenkins :(

Comment: All the other answers are BS and return hostname or 127.0.1.1 etc.
`ifconfig` is what I really want

Answer (score 13):

### From the Web Interface

Go to the node's `Log` link:

[http://jenkins.mycompany.com:8080/computer/my_node_name/log](http://jenkins.mycompany.com:8080/computer/%3Cnode_name%3E/log)

The first line should say something like:

```
JNLP agent connected from /10.11.12.123
```

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

This is very similar to what deepak explained but I added images along the short steps.

In Jenkins UI click:

Manage Jenkins -> Nodes -> Select a node -> Script Console

then run println InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the ip on a Windows slave:

Navigate to the Script Console (*Manage Jenkins* -> *Nodes* -> *Select a node* -> *Script Console*)

```
println "ipconfig".execute().text
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Jenkins job if its in groovy or else echo the ifonfig
sh "/sbin/ifconfig -a | grep inet"

Answer (score -1):

Can also be found through the Jenkins UI:
Manage Jenkins --> Manage Nodes --> Click Node name --> Configure

This should display both the public and private ip address of that node

Comment: I'm guessing people downvoted this because if you're using Java web start, it won't show it; only if you use SSH. I wish people would explain when they downvote.

Comment: This also won't show the node name or ip address of the master.

Comment: Original question doesn't ask for the IP address of the master, only the slaves "Is there away to find the IP address of a slave node from Jenkins itself?" - hence why this answer was provided