# How to fetch IP address of Jenkins Node When I know Computer name

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code setup that fetches nodes instance for multiple nodes that are co-existing for our Jenkins setup:

```
Object nodes = Jenkins.getInstance().getLabel(label).getNodes()

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
    Object computer = nodes[i].getComputer()
    String nodeName = nodes[i].getNodeName()
}
```

Now inside the for loop I have computer and nodename available. But I need to know the IP address of each of these nodes. I am pretty new to groovy and Jenkins, so wanted to know if there is a method that I can call to directly get the IP address inside the for loop above.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930329/finding-ip-of-a-jenkins-node

Comment: So do you think this will work: "computer.getChannel().call(new ListPossibleNames())" ?

Comment: Apply in your code and check which answer is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding IP of a Jenkins node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930329/finding-ip-of-a-jenkins-node)